# Serializing map having value of different types to JSON using Jackson in Java

Tags: java, json, jackson, objectmapper

I would like to serialize a given hashmap into json and deserialize it back to the original map.

Here I would like to make this generic so that it behaves seamlessly regardless of the type of the value.

I am using the following code snippet for  constructing the map and then serailizing it as json:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Object>> argumentNameValueMap = new HashMap<>();

for (int i = 0; i < codeSignature.getParameterNames().length; i++) {
  argumentNameValueMap.put(codeSignature.getParameterNames()[i],
      mapper.convertValue(joinPoint.getArgs()[i],
          Map.class)); <----THIS LINE IS FAILING WHEN ARGUMENT VALUE IS OF PRIMITIVE TYPE.
}

return mapper.writeValueAsString(argumentNameValueMap);
```

This is working fine when the type of value that is going to put into the map is an object but fails while the value is of any primitive type i.e. String/Integer etc.

I can handle this by writing a check if the associated value type is of any primitive type and add if else accordingly.

But I would like to know if there is any better way to do this. Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand the sentence "but fails while it is of any primitive type i.e. String/Integer etc.". String and Integer are objects, not primitive types.

Comment: @k314159 Sure. By this sentence, I meant if the value is of any primitive type then the code in OP does not work.

Comment: What are codeSignature and joinPoint?

Comment: @k314159 they are relevant to Spring aspect. Here I am basically concerned with capturing argument name along with argument value in a map and serialising the map as json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `JSON` specification recognized values are: `JSON Object` - `{...}`, `JSON Array` - `[...]`, `string`, `number`, `false`, `true` and `null`. Only `JSON Object` can be deserialised by default to `Map` and `Map` can be serialised to a `JSON Object`.

In your case you need to handle other types manually and convert them to `Map` instance somehow. You can implement your own `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializationProblemHandler` which allows to intercept conversion mechanism in case of problems.

Below you can find a simple implementation how to do that:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.TreeNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JavaType;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializationProblemHandler;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.ValueInstantiator;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class JsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Object> source = new HashMap<>();
        source.put("pojo", new SomeClass());
        source.put("string", "String-Value");
        source.put("int", 1);
        source.put("null", null);
        source.put("char", 'A');
        source.put("long", Long.MIN_VALUE);
        source.put("list", Arrays.asList(1, 3));
        source.put("array", new int[]{12, 13});

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.addHandler(new Convert2MapDeserializationProblemHandler());

        Map<String, Map<String, Object>> argumentNameValueMap = new HashMap<>();
        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : source.entrySet()) {
            argumentNameValueMap.put(entry.getKey(), mapper.convertValue(entry.getValue(), Map.class));
        }
        argumentNameValueMap.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + " -> " + v));
    }
}

class Convert2MapDeserializationProblemHandler extends DeserializationProblemHandler {
    @Override
    public Object handleMissingInstantiator(DeserializationContext ctxt, Class<?> instClass, ValueInstantiator valueInsta, JsonParser p, String msg) throws IOException {
        if (Map.class.isAssignableFrom(instClass)) {
            Map<String, Object> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
            TreeNode value = p.readValueAsTree();
            map.put("value", value);
            return map;
        }
        return super.handleMissingInstantiator(ctxt, instClass, valueInsta, p, msg);
    }

    @Override
    public Object handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext ctxt, JavaType targetType, JsonToken t, JsonParser p, String failureMsg) throws IOException {
        if (Map.class.isAssignableFrom(targetType.getRawClass())) {
            Map<String, Object> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
            TreeNode value = p.readValueAsTree();
            map.put("value", value);
            return map;
        }
        return super.handleUnexpectedToken(ctxt, targetType, t, p, failureMsg);
    }
}

class SomeClass {
    String stringField = "Value!";

    public String getStringField() {
        return stringField;
    }

    public void setStringField(String stringField) {
        this.stringField = stringField;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "SomeClass{" +
                "stringField='" + stringField + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
pojo -> {stringField=Value!}
string -> {value="String-Value"}
null -> null
array -> {value=[12,13]}
char -> {value="A"}
list -> {value=[1,3]}
int -> {value=1}
long -> {value=-9223372036854775808}
```

Comment: @michael-ziober Thanks for your answer. One small question. I am seeing in the map, you have a hard-coded key as "value". Is it possible to pass the key anyway here, that I would like to put in the map?

Comment: @Joy, on that level key name is not known, only value. Maybe you should not convert "not-`POJO`" values to `Map`? It should be much easier to check this before converting to `Map`. In case it is a primitive you could just create a `Map` with one key-value pair and do not run conversion logic.

Comment: @michael-ziober, actually I had tried the approach as you suggested using isPrimitive()/isPrimitiveWrapper() API of Google-Guava as well as ClassUtils of Apache commons. Both were giving false to the value of class Java.lang.String.

Comment: @Joy, you can always check a package and if class comes from `java.lang` you can treat it as a primitive. I understand you are implementing some aspects and these values are parameters to a method so it should be a reasonable way.